# How can I push the next view controller on a navigation controller programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I push the next view controller on a navigation controller programmatically (without the need of a button)?

I know how to instantiate and present a new controller is the below

```
 var next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlaceInfo") as! PlaceInfoController         
 self.presentViewController(next, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

but I want to push to the next view controller on the navigation controller.
I tried the below **self.navigationController?.pushViewController()** but no success

```
 var next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlaceInfo") as! PlaceInfoController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
```

Comment: Have you checked if `self.navigationController` is `nil` or not?

Comment: it is nil. any idea why?  thank you in advance @Leo

Comment: It means that this viewController is not in a navigation stack,first you have to put it into a navigation stack,then you can push another

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `performSegueWithIdentifier`?

Learn more about this here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSeguePerforming_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSSeguePerforming/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

Comment: yes and the app crashes.     Error:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'PushPlaceView'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'        @rodrigochousal

Comment: The app is crashing because of what @Leo said, the view controller needs to be in a navigation stack to work.